# SQL Query to join two tables by aggregating a column over a time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to run a query between that joins two tables by aggregating a calculated column from "Table B" over a time range, per record from "Table A"

Table A:

```
 Asset       Part              LastChanged        
 A11         RearBearing       2021/04/11
 A30         FrontBearing      2021/01/07
 A54         Shaft             2020/11/19
 A54         FrontBearing      2021/04/18
```

Table B

```
 Asset      EventStart             EventEnd              Revs     Load     Temp
 A54       2021-09-20 19:20:04     2021-09-20 20:31:33   2993     54       189
 A54       2021-09-20 20:40:14     2021-09-20 20:58:23   780      49       155
 A54       2021-09-20 21:05:53     2021-09-20 22:44:21   4728     66       142
 ...       ...................     ...................   ....     ..       ...
```

"Table B" is a collection of load events that all assets have undergone.

I'm trying to see if it's possible to run a SQL query per every record from Table A that will aggregate a calculated column from Table B using EventStart as the column to filter by.

For example, for the **Front Bearing** of asset **A54**, since the date it was last changed (**2021/04/18**) until **today**, I'd like to calculate two things from Table B.

```
-The sum of revolutions
-The sum of (revolutions*load)/temp
```

Then I'd like to repeat this for every Asset/Part record from Table A from their respective Last Changed dates.

If this is very hard to do in SQL I have the option of doing it in code and re-writing another table every 10 minutes or so, but ideally if this could be done directly in SQL I can have an almost real time API set up.

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who might be able to help.

Comment: This is just a basic aggregation query. Maybe the join is throwing you off?

Comment: I think expected results from the sample data would help add clarity.

Comment: What is `temp`?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for `OUTER APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT
    A.Asset,
    A.Part,
    A.LastChanged,
    B.Revs,
    B.RLT
FROM
    [Table A] As A
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT SUM(Revs) As Revs, SUM(1. * Revs * Load / Temp) As RLT
        FROM [Table B] As B
        WHERE B.Asset = A.Asset
        And B.EventStart >= A.LastChanged
    ) As B
;
```

*(The `1. *`  is only there to avoid integer division; if your column types are actually floating-point numbers, you can omit this.)*

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ceacd/2/0)
[Using Apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-apply)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want the ratio of the two values.  `OUTER APPLY` is a good approach.  The code would look like:

```
SELECT A.*, B.Revs, B.Revs_Load,
       B.Revs * 1.0 / B.Revs_Load as ratio
FROM TableA A OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(Revs) As Revs, SUM(Revs * Load) As Revs_Load
      FROM TableB B
      WHERE B.Asset = A.Asset AND
            B.EventStart >= A.LastChanged
     ) B;
```